Why am i getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from config import TOKEN, API_KEY
import aiohttp

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = nextcord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot has connected to Discord")

@bot.command()
async def weather(ctx: commands.Context, *, city):
    url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json"
    params = {
        "key": API_KEY,
        "q": city
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, params=params) as responses:
            data = await responses.json()
            
            print(data)
            location = data["location"]["name"]["localtime"]

I keep getting the TypeError at this line:
location = data["location"]["name"]["localtime"]

TypeError:
string indices must be integers, not 'str'

In the weather API the information is stored in nested dictionaries. I am accessing those value by using location = data["outer_key"]["inner_key"]
The command i am passing is !weather "city_name"
What am i doing wrong?

It looks like data["location"]["name"] does not consist in a dictionary, rather a string, from which python tries string["localtime"].

Look at printed value for data. If you can paste that here then you will get answer easily.

Based on the API documentation for the location object, it looks like "name" and "localtime" are both keys of the location object, so you want
location = data["location"]
location_name = location["name"]
location_localtime = location["localtime"]

or
location_name = data["location"]["name"]
location_localtime = data["location"]["localtime"]

You were getting the TypeError because you were trying to extract the localtime from the name string, and and strings have numeric indexes.
